# Use String as Function handle in Python

Tags: python, function

im currently writing my own event handling system with python. There i allow user to assign callbacks for each event with a function:

```
myEventHandlingSystem.addCallback(event_name, event_callback)
```

However, as each client has a set of event and sometimes the supported event list will be very long. In such situation, manually add each event using the method described above is quite complicated and might also have some mistakes like forgot to assign an event or an event is assigned multiple times with different callbacks by mistake.

What i want to achieve is that as each event has a String name, user should define the callback with exact the same name as the event. So at the end, user just need to provide a list of event, and each callbacks will automatically be associated to the event (of course, the a callback named in other way, the nothing should be assigned to that event) like:

```
SUPPORTED_EVENT1 = 'evt_Event1'
SUPPORTED_EVENT2 = 'evt_Event2'

clientConfig = json.load(configHandle)
# the json config file contains a field of 'SupportedEventList':[SUPPRTED_EVENT1,...]


def evt_Event1(*args):
    ...

myEventHandlingSystem.addCallbackFromEventList(clientConfig['SupportedEventList'])
```

Note that the supportedEventList is alway in form of a string list, where each element is the string contains the name of Event. Also the callback is handeled in the file where class for myEventHandlingSystem is defined

Comment: @Carcigenicate, im asking for how to use sting as indicator for function handles. I think its quite clear here, the supportedEventList here is just an example , its in fact comes from a configuration file (maybe i need to modified it a bit to show that it is from the config file). So it is not that got to make the list of function handles in the way you mentioned, as its basically nothing different to my current solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this would be to have a `dict` with associations between the functions and their names. Remember, functions are first-class objects in python and as such you can store them in a `dict` like you can store references to any other data. Hence you could do something along the lines of:

```py
def evt_Event1(*args):
    ...

ALLOWED_CALLBACKS = {"evt_Event1": evt_Event1}

supportedEventList = ["evt_Event1",...]

for event in supportedEventList:
  myEventHandlingSystem.addCallback(event, ALLOWED_CALLBACKS[event])
```

EDIT: So to address the question as it stands now. There is a function in python called `globals()` which would have a list of the functions defined in a given python file i.e. `{"evt_Event1":<function at ...>}`

You could do:

```py
SUPPORTED_EVENT1 = 'evt_Event1'
SUPPORTED_EVENT2 = 'evt_Event2'

clientConfig = json.load(configHandle)
# the json config file contains a field of 'SupportedEventList':[SUPPRTED_EVENT1,...]


def evt_Event1(*args):
    ...

GLOBALS = globals()
for callback_name in clientConfig['SupportedEventList']:
 eventSystem.addCallback(GLOBALS[callback_name])
```

If you wanted a register type API. You could:
So you could do something along the lines of:

```py
# ./decorator.py

REGISTERED = {}

def register(func):
     REGISTERED[func.__name__] = func
     return func
```

and in the main code

```py
from .decorator import REGISTERED, register

@register
def callback():
    ...
```

Alternatively you could straight away register the new callback into your event handling system using this type of decorator:

```py
def register(func):
    myEventHandlingSystem.addCallback(func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

Also you could check out `pluggy` and similar plug in frameworks that allow people to add plugin functionality which sort of fits your pattern.

Comment: The string lookup seems redundant - you could just make `supportedEventList` a set of functions and be done with it.

Comment: it looks doable, the next question is (as i just modified the question to represent my situation more precisely), the supportedEventList is infact defined in a configuration file (json file). As the name of callbacks are given (i mean in this situation, callback for event1 must be called "evt_Event1"), can i make this dict within the class of myEventHandlingSystem?

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement. You're absolutely right. Corrected.

Comment: So, just to be clear. My original proposal of having an `ALLOWED_CALLBACKS` was implying that you had a set of callbacks that were implemented in your library. You could implement those internally and store the dictionary within the class. However as the @0x5453 pointed out. If you intention is for users to define new custom callbacks and add them - which makes sense - you would use the correct bit of code I showed there.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. It solves exactly the problem im facing. Just curious if i can provide more flexibility here for the user, so that the user can also name the callbacks as they wish but adding a decorator like @SUPPRTED_EVENT1 def unserdefined_func(*args)?